# ezpublish for practical e-commerce?

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, ezpublish

For while now I have been using **ezpublish** as a framework, and CMS when my web projects are based on PHP, and I must say, I have grown accustomed to it because of its flexibility for most scenarios.

However, I've had to build e-commerce sites now and then, and **ezpublish** includes a webshop that caters for the e-commerce needs of your installation, and of-course with all the tools you need to extend, should you need to.

Is it worthwhile and optimal to use the inbuilt webshop for an e-commerce solution, or should I rather go with an all out e-commerce solution like **Magento**, which has made a significant impact in that sector?

Comment: I've just had a client asking for an e-commerce site too. My specialty is Drupal (with Ubercart) and I too was wondering whether switching to Magento was a good idea. I'm curious about what more experienced people have to say about the possibilities...

Comment: What did you decide to do in the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento is great. It's chock full of features that you would normally pay a lot of money for in a shopping cart (or spend an eternity implementing yourself). Mostly anything you don't have in the base installation you can get from the community.

But it's extremely complicated. Expect to step a lot of time setting up your store, as the default install is *not* ready to go. Expect to spend time adding a template, which will take much longer than you expect. Expect to stretch your PHP skills in ways that you cannot anticipate.

Generally, Magento is not the "fast" option, nor the "easy" one, just the good one. If none of that dissuades you, it's a great option :)

Hope that helps. Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 4):

Some have made the choice of using both solutions, connected with each other ( www.ezgento.org ). Can be achieved mostly due to the very open architecture of eZ Publish. I do not have enough insight on the Magento side, so i can not tell whether it is easily "pluggable" too.

I know for fact that some ez Publish Community members are building large-scale e-shops with eZ Publish, either as a pure Content Management tool, serving content and only content to dedicated ecommerce tools, either as an integrated solution, then relying on the built-in webshop module.

I am sure you would get a fruitful discussion if asking your question directly in eZ Publish's community : http://share.ez.no/forums

Hope it helps, 
Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

- eZ Publish has [Payment Gateways](http://projects.ez.no/content/advancedsearch?SearchText=payment)
- It allows you to define precisely segment you category/products/prices/taxes/currencies in a flexible way
- it is secure
- eZ's technology is based on Open Standards and XML, which means that eZ Publish integrates natively with most of the payment gateways, as well as with many leading CRM and ERP solutions like Salesforce.com, SugarCRM, Microsoft Navision or SAP.
- It integrates with Online Marketing Suites in order to segment customers and provide advanced content-centric analytics
- [eZ Find](http://ez.no/eZPublish/Core-features/eZ-Find-Enterprise-Search), built on top of Lucene/solR, gives backthe relevancy of search results, and providing new ways of navigating content (facets, etc.)
- It has a good cache system

See official pres about [eZ Publish + eCommerce](http://ez.no/Customers-solutions/Industries/Retail-E-Commerce) for more infos